# How do I turn off Browser Messages in Moto G?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

My phone keeps on receiving text messages with the Title as 'browser messages' every two hours. Is there any way to stop them?

Edit:
It is a proper SMS.

Comment: Are you actually receiving text messages (sms)? Or are you just getting a notification that has the title 'browser messages'?

Comment: I am actually receiving text messages.

Answer (score 3):

There will be an app called **BrowserMessage** in your phone. To disable that go to Settings > Apps > All > Select the BrowserMessage app and **Disable it**.

Hope this helps you and whoever facing this irritation :)

[image]